# Using expect to run "nc -w 3 -z $IP 22" command on macOS but get long waiting timeout

Tags: linux, shell, tcl, expect

I using linux expect command to execute "nc -w 3 -z $IP 22" command on macOS.

I expected timeout after 3 seconds but I got 1m 15s (Due to "nc" command can setting timeout via "-w" argument).

I run the same code at other linux(Debian 7.8, ubuntu 14.04) machines are normally.

Who can tell me why I got the different result between linux and macOS ?

Following content is my source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set DUT_IP "192.168.1.2"

if {0!=[catch {exec sh -c "nc -w 3 -z $DUT_IP 22 && echo \$?"}]} {
  send_user "Cannot connect to DUT $DUT_IP\n"
  exit -1
} else {
  puts "IP exist"
}
```

Comment: Probably, this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18578565/nc-netcat-on-mac-os-x-10-8-4-gets-stuck

Comment: Though, you in fact don't use any Expect feature (`send_user` can be easily replaced by `puts`), so you could switch to `tclsh`. And more, it'd be better in my opinion to get rid of an external program and just use `socket` to check host availability.

Comment: To Sergei Golovan:
Thanks for your recommends, in fact I use grate more '''''expect "xxx" { do something } ''''' in my source code. I just met the timeout problem in the description.

Comment: I see delays on OSX relating to name resolution, especially impacting handling `localhost`. (There's something really weird going on there.) You might need to carefully tune exactly what you do.